# Верстка русскоязычных документов в RMarkdown

Tags: r, кириллица, markdown, tex, rstudio

Использую *RMarkdown* для верстки простеньких документов с использованием *TeX*. С англоязычными документами проблем не возникает. С русскоязычными файлами удается скомпилировать, но синтаксис *TeX* в нем не работает.
Пробовал разные финтифлюшки в преамбуле, но ничего не вышло.

Answer (score 2):

В дополнительных опциях нужно указать язык.

```
---
title: Тема
subtitle: Подтема
author: Автор
date: \today
toc: true
toc-depth: 2
navigation: frame
fontenc: T2A
lang: russian
babel-lang: russian
---
```

Подробнее см документацию к Rmarkdown и pandoc. Например: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#latex_options

Comment: В настоящий момент `lang: russian` вызывает ошибку `[WARNING] Invalid 'lang' value 'russian'. Use an IETF language tag like 'en-US'.` Посему взамен следует использовать строку `lang: ru-RU`.